# Can I fit a training tyre to my bike wheel?

Tags: mountain-bike, tyre-width

I have a mountain bike with a tyre marked 26x2.00 and I'd like to fit a training tyre so I can use my bike inside.

I know that the 26 refers to the diameter of the wheel and the 2.00 is the width of the tyre but I have my eye on a training tyre which is marked 26x1.25.  Clearly the tyre width is smaller which is not a problem but what I don't understand is how I know whether it will fit my wheel rim.

Firstly, I don't know the correct place to measure the rim (it measures 26mm on the outside) but secondly how do I know which tyres will fit which rims?  Is this listed on the tyre somewhere to say it fits a specific width wheel?

Thanks

Comment: The main requirement for a "training tire" is that it have a relatively smooth tread.  Re the tire width, there's no hard and fast rule (so long as the width is in decimal -- don't ask), but 1.25 is probably a hair on the narrow side for a rim designed for a 2.00.

Comment: Thanks.  What do you think a minimum I could get away with?  I'm going to use it with my magnetic trainer but I want a thinner tyre to try and keep the noise to an absolute minimum... Thinking that smaller would have less contact hence less noise???

Comment: @ojs it most certainly does :).  I'd like to download a copy of that catalog...is it available online? I've had a look around but J&Bs importers brings up a lot of irrelevant results!!

Comment: The other option would be to get an extra rear wheel with a narrower 26'' rim to fit your narrower training tyre. But you'd need to check for the correct width between drop-outs.